# Finding cartesian product with PHP associative arrays

Tags: php, algorithm, associative-array, cartesian-product

Say that I have an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [arm] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
        )
    [gender] => Array
        (
            [0] => Female
            [1] => Male
        )
    [location] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vancouver
            [1] => Calgary
        )
)
```

How can I find the cartesian product while preserving the keys of the outer associative array and using them in the inner ones? The result of the algorithm should be this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [arm] => A
            [gender] => Female
            [location] => Vancouver
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [arm] => A
            [gender] => Female
            [location] => Calgary
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [arm] => A
            [gender] => Male
            [location] => Vancouver
        )

...etc.
```

I've looked up quite a number of cartesian product algorithms but I'm getting stuck on the specifics of how to preserve the associative keys. The current algorithm I am using gives numerical indices only:

```
    $result = array();
    foreach ($map as $a) {
        if (empty($result)) {
            $result = $a;
            continue;
        }
        $res = array();
        foreach ($result as $r) {
            foreach ($a as $v) {
                $res[] = array_merge((array)$r, (array)$v);
            }
        }
        $result = $res;
    }

    print_r($result);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Concatenate values of n arrays in php (Feb 2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2246493/367456)

Comment: This seems like a transpose action instead of cartesian product.

Comment: Have a look at [cartesianProduct](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#cartesianproductsequences) from nSPL

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Rationale

Assume that we have an input array `$input` with `N` sub-arrays, as in your example. Each
sub-array has `Cn` items, where `n` is its index inside `$input`, and its key is `Kn`. I will refer to the `i`th item of the `n`th sub-array as `Vn,i`.

The algorithm below can be proved to work (barring bugs) by induction:

1. For N = 1, the cartesian product is simply `array(0 => array(K1 => V1,1), 1 => array(K1 => V1,2), ... )` -- C1 items in total. This can be done with a simple `foreach`.
2. Assume that `$result` already holds the cartesian product of the first N-1 sub-arrays. The cartesian product of `$result` and the Nth sub-array can be produced this way:
3. In each item (array) inside `$product`, add the value `KN => VN,1`. Remember the resulting item (with the added value); I 'll refer to it as `$item`.

4a) For each array inside `$product`:

4b) For each value in the set `VN,2 ... VN,CN`, add to `$product` a copy of `$item`, but change the value with the key `KN` to `VN,m` (for all `2 <= m <= CN`).

The two iterations 4a (over `$product`) and 4b (over the Nth input sub-array) ends up with `$result` having `CN` items for every item it had before the iterations, so in the end `$result` indeed contains the cartesian product of the first N sub arrays.

Therefore the algorithm will work for any N.

### Code

```
function cartesian($input) {
    $result = array();

    while (list($key, $values) = each($input)) {
        // If a sub-array is empty, it doesn't affect the cartesian product
        if (empty($values)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Seeding the product array with the values from the first sub-array
        if (empty($result)) {
            foreach($values as $value) {
                $result[] = array($key => $value);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Second and subsequent input sub-arrays work like this:
            //   1. In each existing array inside $product, add an item with
            //      key == $key and value == first item in input sub-array
            //   2. Then, for each remaining item in current input sub-array,
            //      add a copy of each existing array inside $product with
            //      key == $key and value == first item of input sub-array

            // Store all items to be added to $product here; adding them
            // inside the foreach will result in an infinite loop
            $append = array();

            foreach($result as &$product) {
                // Do step 1 above. array_shift is not the most efficient, but
                // it allows us to iterate over the rest of the items with a
                // simple foreach, making the code short and easy to read.
                $product[$key] = array_shift($values);
                
                // $product is by reference (that's why the key we added above
                // will appear in the end result), so make a copy of it here
                $copy = $product;

                // Do step 2 above.
                foreach($values as $item) {
                    $copy[$key] = $item;
                    $append[] = $copy;
                }

                // Undo the side effecst of array_shift
                array_unshift($values, $product[$key]);
            }

            // Out of the foreach, we can add to $results now
            $result = array_merge($result, $append);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

### Usage

```
$input = array(
    'arm' => array('A', 'B', 'C'),
    'gender' => array('Female', 'Male'),
    'location' => array('Vancouver', 'Calgary'),
);

print_r(cartesian($input));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you did  
`while (list($key, $values) = each($input)) {`  

instead of  

`foreach ($input as $key => $values) {`

Comment: @FunBeans: No reason. Actually I am myself surprised that I chose to write it like that, even though it was several years ago.

Answer (score 64):

Here is optimized version of @Jon's cartesian function:

```
function cartesian($input) {
    $result = array(array());

    foreach ($input as $key => $values) {
        $append = array();

        foreach($result as $product) {
            foreach($values as $item) {
                $product[$key] = $item;
                $append[] = $product;
            }
        }

        $result = $append;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Read more about the math behind this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

See more examples of this algorithm in different languages: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_two_or_more_lists

Comment: FYI, this technique returns a product in the 'order' I would expect - the accepted answer does not.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks for noticing this, I guess that's due to the fact that "array_merge" is used in the accepted solution.

Answer (score 11):

Why not use a recursive generator ... memory issues: close to none
(and it´s beautiful)

```
function cartesian($a)
{
    if ($a)
    {
        if($u=array_pop($a))
            foreach(cartesian($a)as$p)
                foreach($u as$v)
                    yield $p+[count($p)=>$v];
    }
    else
        yield[];
}
```

note: this does not preserve keys; but it´s a start.

This should do:

```
function acartesian(array $a)
{
    if ($a) {
        $k = array_key_last($a);
        if ($u = array_pop($a)) {
            foreach (acartesian($a) as $p) {
                foreach ($u as $v) {
                    yield $p + [$k => $v];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        yield[];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the c() function ?

Comment: @PolDellaiera Oops I renamed the functions themselves after golfing; but forgot to modify the recursion calls. Fixed.

Comment: How about tha callstack? Whats the maximum depth of nested calls?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU PHP default settings have no limit; but it´s a good point. I may test memory consumption one day.

Comment: I asked because in your case the callstack is equal with the number of level0 items in the input array and this can become a problem with long arrays.

Comment: Beautiful and Efficient solution! +12345

Comment: Hi Titus, your solution has been ported and enhanced in a dedicated library: https://github.com/bpolaszek/cartesian-product (adds a count() method to count the number of combinations without ever iterating). Big thanks to you!

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Ben did a performance test with his class he built from my post: He didn´t measure recursion depth; but approx 9.7M combinations from a 5x10 array at a peak usage of ~ 1 MB.

Answer (score 10):

In PHP 7 @Serg's answer can be shortened to:

```
function cartesian(array $input)
{
    $result = [[]];
    foreach ($input as $key => $values) {
        $append = [];
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            foreach ($result as $data) {
                $append[] = $data + [$key => $value];
            }
        }
        $result = $append;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I could come up with:

```
function inject($elem, $array) {
    return array_map(function ($n) use ($elem) { return array_merge((array)$elem, (array)$n); }, $array);
}

function zip($array1, $array2) {
    return array_reduce($array1, function ($v, $n) use ($array2) { return array_merge($v, inject($n, $array2));  }, array());
}

function cartesian_product($array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $prod = array_shift($array);
    $prod = array_reduce($array, 'zip', $prod);
    return array_map(function ($n) use ($keys) { return array_combine($keys, $n); }, $prod);
}
```

---

*(Using pseudo array/list/dictionary notation below since PHP is simply too verbose for such things.)*

The `inject` function transforms `a, [b]` into `[(a,b)]`, i.e. it injects a single value into each value of an array, returning an array of arrays. It doesn't matter whether `a` or `b` already is an array, it'll always return a two dimensional array.

```
inject('a', ['foo', 'bar'])
    =>  [('a', 'foo'), ('b', 'bar')]
```

The `zip` function applies the `inject` function to each element in an array.

```
zip(['a', 'b'], ['foo', 'bar'])
    =>  [('a', 'foo'), ('a', 'bar'), ('b', 'foo'), ('b', 'bar')]
```

Note that this actually produces a cartesian product, so `zip` is a slight misnomer. Simply applying this function to all elements in a data set in succession gives you the cartesian product for an array of any length.

```
zip(zip(['a', 'b'], ['foo', 'bar']), ['42', '76'])
    =>  [('a', 'foo', '42'), ('a', 'foo', '76'), ('a', 'bar', '42'), …]
```

This does not contain the keys, but since the elements are all in order within the result set, you can simply re-inject the keys into the result.

```
array_combine(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], ['a', 'foo', '42'])
    =>  [ key1 : 'a', key2 : 'foo', key3 : '42' ]
```

Applying this to all elements in the product gives the desired result.

You can collapse the above three functions into a single long statement if you wish (which would also clear up the misnomers).

---

An "unrolled" version without anonymous functions for PHP <= 5.2 would look like this:

```
function inject($elem, $array) {
    $elem = (array)$elem;
    foreach ($array as &$a) {
        $a = array_merge($elem, (array)$a);
    }
    return $array;
}

function zip($array1, $array2) {
    $prod = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $a) {
        $prod = array_merge($prod, inject($a, $array2));
    }
    return $prod;
}

function cartesian_product($array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $prod = array_shift($array);
    $prod = array_reduce($array, 'zip', $prod);

    foreach ($prod as &$a) {
        $a = array_combine($keys, $a);
    }
    return $prod;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
function getAllVariations($input) {
    $result = array();
    $cnt = array_product(array_map('count', $input));
    $step = 1;
    foreach ($input as $key=>$array) {
        for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                for ($k=0; $k<$step; $k++) {
                    $result[$i+$k][$key] = $value;
                }
                $i += $step;
            }
            $i--;
        }
        $step = $step * count($array);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$input = array(
    'arm' => array('A', 'B', 'C'),
    'gender' => array('Female', 'Male'),
    'location' => array('Vancouver', 'Calgary'),
    'name' => array('Rio', 'Mark')
);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(getAllVariations($input));
```

Answer (score 3):

If memory consumption is important or you don't need all the combinations in the end you could use an iterator to generate one combination at a time. If you need all the combinations you can use `iterator_to_array`.

```
function cartezianIterator($inputArray)
{
    $maximumPosition = array_map('count', $inputArray);
    $position = array_pad([], count($inputArray), 0);

    while (false !== ($item = buildItemAtPosition($inputArray, $position))) {

        yield $item;

        $position = incrementPosition($position, $maximumPosition);
    }
}

function buildItemAtPosition($inputArray, $positions)
{
    if ($positions[0] >= count($inputArray[0])) {
        return false;
    }

    $item = [];
    foreach ($inputArray as $rowIndex => $row) {
        $position = $positions[$rowIndex];

        $item[] = $row[$position];
    }

    return $item;
}

function incrementPosition($position, $maximumPosition)
{
    $digitToIncrement = count($position) - 1;

    do {
        $position[$digitToIncrement]++;

        if ($position[$digitToIncrement] < $maximumPosition[$digitToIncrement] || 0 === $digitToIncrement) {
            //no overflow
            break;
        }

        //overflow, reset to zero and increment parent digit
        $position[$digitToIncrement] = 0;

        $digitToIncrement--;
    } while ($digitToIncrement >= 0);

    return $position;
}
```

Then, to get one solution at a time you could use a `foreach` or `next`, like this:

```
$iterator = cartezianIterator($inputArray);

//of course, you need to do something with the result...
$combination = next($iterator);
$combination = next($iterator);
$combination = next($iterator);
$combination = next($iterator);
$combination = next($iterator);
$combination = next($iterator);
```

This solution is very very fast if you need only a few combinations. 
Also, the memory consumption is very low (it uses a flat `array` to store some `integers`).

Note: recursive functions are not used.

Answer (score 2):

I quickly adjusted your code a bit , my attempt is crude i think but see if this works as you want:

```
$result = array();
$nm = '';
foreach ($map as $name => $a) {
    if (empty($result)) {
        $result = $a;
        $nm = $name;
        continue;
    }

    $res = array();
    foreach ($result as $r) {
        foreach ($a as $v) {
            $myr = $r;
            $myv = $v;
            if(!is_array($r)) $myr = array($nm => $r);
            if(!is_array($v)) $myv = array($name => $v);

            $res[] = array_merge($myr, $myv);
        }
    }
    $result = $res;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a database to do this?

It's easy in MySQL..

```
table arm
   id integer primary key
   label char

table gender
   id integer primary key
   gender enum('male','female')

table location
   id integer primary key
   city varchar(255)
```

Then do a query

```
$query = mysql_query(" 
  SELECT a.label, g.gender, l.city
  FROM arm a
  CROSS JOIN gender g
  CROSS JOIN location l
  ORDER BY a.id
") or die("Could not execute query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{
   ....
}
```

And read that out:

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I can not do this particular problem in a database. I will definitely use your query as a reference if I do later on, however.

Answer (score 0):

One algorithm is to expand at each step the previous results with the current step items:

```
function cartezian1($inputArray)
{
    $results = [];

    foreach ($inputArray as $group) {
        $results = expandItems($results, $group);
    }

    return $results;
}

function expandItems($sourceItems, $tails)
{
    $result = [];

    if (empty($sourceItems)) {
        foreach ($tails as $tail) {
            $result[] = [$tail];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    foreach ($sourceItems as $sourceItem) {
        foreach ($tails as $tail) {
            $result[] = array_merge($sourceItem, [$tail]);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This solution uses memory to store the all combinations then returns them all at once. So, it's fast but it needs a lot of memory. Also, recursive functions are not used.