# Is there a better way to implement those nested loops?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Suppose having three arrays:

```
char [] one = {'a','b','c'};
char [] two = {'1','2','3'};
char [] three = {'x','y','z'};
```

If I want to print them like this:

```
a 1 x
a 1 y
a 1 z

a 2 x
a 2 y
.....
c 3 z
```

I must create three nested loops;

```
for(char i : one)
  for(char j : two)
    for(char k : three)
       //.....
```

Suppose if I have 7 arrays, it will be 7 nested loops.

Is there a better way to do that or an API maybe? I know you're probably asking why you do such a thing, It's just the mater of thinking.

Comment: Make an array of `char[]`s and call a recursive function?

Comment: Actually the way you've described it it's only 2 nested loops.  Look carefully.  And yes you can write a function that iterates over an arbitrary sequence of arrays.

Comment: @Eric: Any Idea how to it?

Comment: @Gene: thanks for correcting me, if you can, the Pseudocode code will be enough for me.

Comment: Okay.  Pseudocode is there as Java!  Looks same as @nneonneo except no separate methods for increment and print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use an array of indices.  Update them like the odometer in a car: least significant index then if overflow set that to zero and move on to the next...  When no overflow, the update is done.  Go ahead and print. When there's an overflow of the last index, printing is done.

```
// Accept an array of character arrays and print a nest
// of their contents.
static void print(char [] [] a) {
    int n_arrays = a.length;
    int [] indices = new int[n_arrays];  // All set to 0 by java
    // Decrement so that first increment is to all zeros. Avoids test for empty arrays.
    indices[n_arrays - 1] = -1; 
    for (int j = 0;;) {
        // Increment indices.
        for (j = n_arrays - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (++indices[j] >= a[j].length) {
                indices[j] = 0;
            }
            else {
                break;  // No overflow. Increment is complete.
            }
        }
        if (j < 0) {
            break; // Last index overflowed.  We're done.
        }
        // Print.
        for (int i = 0; i < n_arrays; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][indices[i]]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// Varargs version.
static void printArgs(char [] ... a) {
    print(a);
}

static char [] one = {'a','b','c'};
static char [] two = {'1','2','3'};
static char [] three = {'x','y','z'};

public static void main(String[] a) {
    print(new char [] [] { one, two, three } );
    printArgs(one, two, three);
}
```

Comment: +1, very clear answer, just convert the `char[][]a` to `char[]...a` will be great. Is this also `O(k * n^k)` ? As there is no recursion only one nested loop!

Comment: @Sasha This has the same cost as the equivalent set of nested loops.

Comment: @Sasha okay I added a varargs call. I find that almost always when I write a varargs function I end up also needing the array version, too.

Comment: Yes, and please [**see this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028344/is-there-a-better-way-to-implement-those-nested-loops/18038208#18038208)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach based on maintaining an explicit array of indices (no recursion or nested loops):

```
static boolean incrementIndices(char[][] arrs, int[] inds) {
    int n = arrs.length;
    for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(inds[i] < arrs[i].length-1) {
            inds[i]++;
            return true;
        }
        inds[i] = 0;
    }
    return false; // could not increment further
}

static void printIndices(char[][] arrs, int[] inds) {
    int n = arrs.length;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        System.out.print(arrs[i][inds[i]]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static final void main(String[] args) {
    char [] one = {'a','b','c'};
    char [] two = {'1','2','3'};
    char [] three = {'x','y','z'};

    char[][] arrs = {one, two, three};
    int[] inds = new int[3];

    do {
        printIndices(arrs, inds);
    } while(incrementIndices(arrs, inds));
}
```

Output:

```
a1x
a1y
a1z
a2x
a2y
a2z
a3x
a3y
a3z
b1x
b1y
b1z
b2x
b2y
b2z
b3x
b3y
b3z
c1x
c1y
c1z
c2x
c2y
c2z
c3x
c3y
c3z
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to create nested loops you can use recursion and varargs. Here is method that will accept your arrays at the end of its arguments

```
// StringBuilder will act like stack that will contain elements that need to
// be printed
public static void printArrays(int arrayIndex, StringBuilder sb, char[]... arrays){

    for (char c : arrays[arrayIndex]) {
        sb.append(c);//add character from current array to stack

        // if we have more arrays use this method again but this time 
        // on next array (by passing increased value of arrayIndex) 
        if (arrayIndex < arrays.length - 1)
            printArrays(arrayIndex + 1, sb, arrays);

        // if we don't have more arrays print current combination of letters 
        if (arrayIndex == arrays.length - 1)
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        // we are here so we iterated via all arrays, and current character 
        // was already used so we can remove it safely 
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

usage

```
char[] one = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char[] two = { '1', '2', '3' };
char[] three = { 'x', 'y', 'z' };
char[] four = {'!', '@', '#', '$'};

printArrays(0, new StringBuilder(), one, two, three, four);
```

Comment: +1 varargs is exactly what I was going to suggest, but I would have left the StringBuilder out and just used string + string and used recursion. It would make the code a lot neater and StringBuilder is an optimization that may not be needed. (I might have a go later)

Comment: I was going to suggest something along a similar line but opted for a more generic solution instead. I think this could be improved with a statically allocated array to put the `char`s into, instead of having to manage a stack. You'd fill each slot of that array as you recursed and print the full array at the end.

Comment: +1, This is really a good answer too, what will be the Big-O of this, O(N^2) ?

Comment: @nneonneo yes, that would be nice improvement, but now I am going to sleep so feel free to post it in separate answer (you will get my +1 tomorrow :D )

Comment: @Sasha: `O(k * n^k)` where `n` is the length of each array (assuming they're all the same) and `k` is the number of arrays. (Note that any algorithm must output k * n^k characters, so they can't be any more efficient).

Comment: @nneonneo: comparing to your answer(in time complicity), it's the same result?

Comment: Yes. The main difference is that my solution is not specific for printing characters (you can replace `printIndices` with some other functionality easily), and that mine doesn't use recursion. But time complexities are the same.

Comment: FYI I've posted my (characteristically terse) version for comparison and interest only. It's inefficient for the computer, but efficient for reading/writing, and it works :)

Comment: @Bohemian And there goes  +1 for your answer (like for most of answers  here).

Answer (score 3):

This is a recursive solution that uses the convenient varargs parameter, thus working for any number of arrays:

```
public static String combinations(String s, char[]... arrays) {
    if (arrays.length == 0) return s + "\n";
    String result = "";
    for (char c : arrays[0])
        result += combinations(s + c, Arrays.copyOfRange(arrays, 1, arrays.length));
    return result;
}
```

It's not that efficient, but it is brief.

You could call it directly with a blank string to start, but a public wrapper function makes a nicer API:

```
public static String combinations(char[]... arrays) {
    return combinations("", arrays);
}
```

Here's some test code:

```
char[] one = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char[] two = { '1', '2', '3' };
char[] three = { 'x', 'y', 'z' };
char[] four = { 'm', 'n', 'o' };
System.out.println(combinations(one, two, three, four));
```

Output:

```
a1xm
a1xn
a1xo
a1ym
a1yn
a1yo
a1zm
a1zn
a1zo
a2xm
a2xn
a2xo
a2ym
a2yn
a2yo
a2zm
a2zn
a2zo
a3xm
a3xn
a3xo
a3ym
a3yn
a3yo
a3zm
a3zn
a3zo
b1xm
b1xn
b1xo
b1ym
b1yn
b1yo
b1zm
b1zn
b1zo
b2xm
b2xn
b2xo
b2ym
b2yn
b2yo
b2zm
b2zn
b2zo
b3xm
b3xn
b3xo
b3ym
b3yn
b3yo
b3zm
b3zn
b3zo
c1xm
c1xn
c1xo
c1ym
c1yn
c1yo
c1zm
c1zn
c1zo
c2xm
c2xn
c2xo
c2ym
c2yn
c2yo
c2zm
c2zn
c2zo
c3xm
c3xn
c3xo
c3ym
c3yn
c3yo
c3zm
c3zn
c3zo
```

Comment: +1, Waw, headache, this is 1 honer thinking about this recursion, please don't tell me you really know what's happening in this line `result += combinations(s + c, Arrays.copyOfRange(arrays, 1, arrays.length));`

Comment: @sasha well.. I did write that line, and it works, so yeah! I confess I deliberately in-lined the call to copyOfRange to save a line if code, giving it a more "java kung fu" look. I'll add an explanation of what's going on (a bit later)

Answer (score 2):

first you need to merge all arrays

```
char[] one = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
char[] two = {'1', '2', '3'};
char[] three = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
char[] four = {'m', 'n', 'o'};
char[][] a = new char[4][];
a[0] = one;
a[1] = two;
a[2] = three;
a[3] = four;
```

then you can print what you want with 2 `for` like this

```
int[] index = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(3, 4); i++) {
    int current = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        index[j] = current % 3;
        current /= 3;
    }
    int k=0;
    for (int j=index.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
        System.out.print(a[k][index[j]]+" ");
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but considering to my output, it's in the inverse order to my output, +1 :)

Comment: you are right. i correct the last `for` with a little dirty work :)

Comment: Your answer is great as I said, but need little repairing, the output the first output should be [ `a 1 x m` , `a 1 x n` , `a 1 x o`..... `c 3 z o`] :)