# Checking characters in an array to build palindrome list

Tags: java, arrays, palindrome

I need to make an array, and fill it with 25 5-digit palindromic numbers.  I made a method for a previous assignment that used a for loop to output it in reverse.  For this one, I wanted to do it all in arrays, to learn something new.  I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18028556/4221094) that I could make generate 00000 - 99999 by adding two chars, and making all of the ranges 0 - 9.  *See bottom of post for full code.*

```
char[] digit1 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
```

To clarify, digit1 is used in main(), like this:

```
char[] digit1 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
char[] digit2 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
char[] digit3 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
char[] digit4 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
char[] digit5 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

char[][] arrs = {digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5};
int[] inds = new int[5];
```

I tried converting the output part of the printIndices method to a String, thinking I could use either charAt, or StringBuilder.reverse().  Right now I have this:

```
String output = String.valueOf(arrs[i][inds[i]]);
System.out.print(output);
```

Which works fine, but if I try to make this:

```
String palindrome = new StringBuilder(output).reverse().toString();
System.out.print(palindrome);
```

I get the exact same characters out as before - am I correct in thinking that if 00001 were reversed using that method, the result would be 10000?

If I use charAt:

```
char output1 = output.charAt(1);
System.out.print(output1);
```

I get the following error for any value other than charAt(0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at PalindromeArray.printIndices(PalindromeArray.java:31)
at PalindromeArray.main(PalindromeArray.java:51)
Java Result: 1
```

If I use charAt(0), it prints all the numbers, which makes me think that they aren't being treated as individual characters that can be picked apart, hence getting an error if I try to access anything past the first one.

```
public class PalindromeArray

{
    static char[] digit1 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    static char[] digit2 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    static char[] digit3 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    static char[] digit4 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    static char[] digit5 = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

static boolean incrementIndices(char[][] arrs, int[] inds) 
{
int n = arrs.length;
for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    if(inds[i] < arrs[i].length - 1) 
    {
        inds[i]++;
        return true;
    }
    inds[i] = 0;
}
return false; // could not increment further
}

static void printIndices(char[][] arrs, int[] inds) 
{
int n = arrs.length;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{

    String output = String.valueOf(arrs[i][inds[i]]);

    for(char c1: digit1)
{
    for(char c2: digit1)
    {
        for(char c3: digit1)
        {
            for(char c4: digit1)
            {
                for(char c5: digit1)
                {
                    String tempCheck = ""+c1+c2+c3+c4+c5;
                    if(isPalindrome(tempCheck))
                    {
                        System.out.println(tempCheck);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    System.out.print(output);


}
System.out.println();
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(String str)
{
String opposite = "";
for(int a = str.length()-1; a > 0; a++)
{
    opposite += str.charAt(a);
}
return opposite.equals(str); 
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{


    char[][] arrs = {digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5};
    int[] inds = new int[5];

    do 
    {
        printIndices(arrs, inds);
    } 
    while(incrementIndices(arrs, inds));
 }

}
```

Comment: What do you get if you print `output` before trying to access it's second character with `charAt(1)`?

Comment: I am a bit lost by reading your question...cannot understand your problem, you defined `digit1` array, but never used, who knows what are `arrs, inds ...` what is your ultimate goal? generate an array, which has 25 5-digit palindromic numbers? does it matter which 25 numbers?

Comment: Added clarification for the digit1... part.
@OlaviMustanoja, I get "0" out, then the previously mentioned StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.
It doesn't matter what numbers.  I want to generate a list, then pick some randomly out of it.  The ultimate goal is to do that, and then figure out which are odd, and which are even.  I had that working previously with an array I just filled with numbers; take modulus 2 of the number, if it's equal to 0, it's odd.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
Project Name: PalindromeLab
Programmer: Jack
Class: Computer Science
Date: 10/14/16
Description: Simple Palindrome Programm
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewPalindromeLab
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Welcome to Palindrome Converter");
      System.out.print("Enter in what you want Palindromeinated ==> ");
      String palin = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("The origional was: " + palin);

      palin = palin.toLowerCase();

      int length = palin.length();

      char[] tempCharArray = new char[length];
      char[] charArray = new char[length];

      for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
      {
         tempCharArray[i] = palin.charAt(i);
      } 

      for(int k=0; k<length; k++)
      {
         charArray[k] = tempCharArray[length - 1 - k];
      }

      String reversePalin = new String (charArray);
      String reverseNewPalin = "";
      reverseNewPalin = reversePalin.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

      System.out.println("The reversed word is: " + reverseNewPalin);

      if (reversePalin.equals(palin))
      {
         System.out.println("This is a palindrome!");
      }
      else      
      {
         System.out.println("This is not a palindrome!");
      }
   }
}

/*
The following is the Output of the program:
Welcome to Palindrome Converter
Enter in what you want Palindromeinated ==>  Hello
The origional was:  Hello
The reversed word is: olleh
This is not a palindrome!
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just create a method like

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str)
{
    String opposite = "";
    for(int a = str.length()-1;a>0;a++)
    {
        opposite+=str.charAt(a);
    }
    return opposite.equals(str);
}
```

Edit: I'm going to write the way to implement it.

```
    for(char c1: digit1)
    {
        for(char c2: digit1)
        {
            for(char c3: digit1)
            {
                for(char c4: digit1)
                {
                    for(char c5: digit1)
                    {
                        String tempCheck = ""+c1+c2+c3+c4+c5;
                        if(isPalindrome(tempCheck))
                        {
                            System.out.println(tempCheck);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added it in as a method, and then this bit into printIndices():

`String output = String.valueOf(arrs[i][inds[i]]);`
        `isPalindrome(output);`
        `if (isPalindrome(output))`
        `{`
            `System.out.print(output);`
        `}`
The result is no output.  If I change the boolean to if false, I get all the numbers.

Comment: So, this runs a for-each for each character of digit1, yes?  I now get String index out of range: 5, referenced to this line:

`opposite += str.charAt(a);`

Comment: Could you show me your entire code please? It's a bit hard trying to recognize your problems.

Comment: Added at bottom of post.

Initially, the digit1...digit5 variables were local to main(), I made them global due to your method referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up completely dumping the code and going a different route.  Borrowed part from a Java forum where someone was doing the same exercise, improved it with a random number generator, made the range of ints to fill make sense for the project, and added counters to total the number of palindromes.

Thank you all to those who contributed - I'm learning a lot about what can and cannot be done.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class PalindromeArray
{
static void arrayFill()
{
  int evens = 0, odds = 0;
  int []palindrome = new int [25];
  int j = 0;
  for(int i = 10001; i < 100000; i++) //Start our counter at the first 5-digit palindrome
  {
    String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s1); //Strings enables us to use sb.reverse for a quick and easy check
    if(s1.equals(sb.reverse().toString()))
    {
        Random r = new Random(); //PRNG so the same numbers don't come up every time
        i = r.nextInt((99999 - 10001) + 1) + 10001; //Ensure generated seed is in desired range
        palindrome[j++] = i;
        if(j == 25)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  {
    if(palindrome[i]%2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("The palindrome at subscript " + i + " = " + palindrome[i] + " --> even");
        evens++;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The palindrome at subscript " + i + " = " + palindrome[i] + " --> odd");
        odds++;
    }
  }

  System.out.println("\nThe total number of even palindromes is " + evens);
  System.out.println("\nThe total number of odd palindromes is " + odds);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   arrayFill();
}
}
```