# PHP merging 3 arrays

Tags: php

I have 3 arrays:

```
array(1, 5, 1);
array(3, 2, 7, 5 ,4);
array(4, 3, 6, 5)
```

I want to merge them and get such result:

```
array(
    array(1, 3, 4),
    array(5, 2, 3),
    array(1, 7, 6),
    array(5, 5),
    array(4)
);
```

What is the easiest way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959127/php-array-join-each-sub-array-together-probability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the latest version of PHP (5.5), you can use this:

```
$input = array(
    array(1,5,1),
    array(3,2,7,5,4),
    array(4,3,6,5)
);
$output = array_column($input,null);
```

If you don't have the latest version, see [the original PHP version](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column) for a shim.

Alternatively, for this specific case (ie. a specialised shim), try this:

```
$input = array(...); // see code block above
$output = array();
foreach($input as $arr) foreach($arr as $i=>$v) $output[$i][] = $v;
```

Comment: Nice! Directly what I want!

Answer (score 5):

```
$arrs = array(
  array(1, 5, 1),
  array(3, 2, 7, 5, 4),
  array(4, 3, 6, 5),
);

$result = array();
$num_arrs = count($arrs);
for($i = 0; $i < $num_arrs; $i++){
  $size = count($arrs[$i]);
  for($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++){
    if(!isset($result[$j]))
      $result[$j] = array();
    $result[$j][] = $arrs[$i][$j];
  }
}
```

### Demo

Comment: `.push()` in PHP? What is it?

Comment: @VahidHallaji Mixed up languages with Javascript. I've edited since then though

Comment: Good solution, thanks, but @Kolink solution is a little bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrays = array(
  array(1, 5, 1),
  array(3, 2, 7, 5 ,4),
  array(4, 3, 6, 5)
);
$combined = array();
foreach($arrays as $array) {
  foreach($array as $index => $val) {
     if(!isset($combined[$index])) $combined[$index] = array();
     $combined[$index][] = $val;
} }
```

After that `$combined` holds what you want.

Comment: Good solution, thanks, but @Kolink solution is a little bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php%E2%80%8E)

```
<?php
  $a  = array( 1, 5, 1 );
  $b  = array( 3, 2, 7, 5 ,4 );
  $c  = array( 4, 3, 6, 5 );

  $d  = array_map( function() {
    return array_filter( func_get_args() );
  }, $a, $b, $c );

  print_r( $d );
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: Good solution, thanks, but @Kolink solution is a little bit simpler.