# automatically generate function for

Tags: php

i have a simple code

data :

```
$data1 = array('1','2','3','4');
$data2 = array('1','2','3','4');
$data3 = array('1','2','3');
```

Logic :

```
for($a = 0; $a < count($data1); $a++){
    for($b = 0; $b < count($data2); $b++){
        for($c = 0; $c < count($data3); $c++){
        echo $data1[$a].$data2[$b].$data3[$c].'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

in this sample total data is 3, if i have 4 data how to build logic will generate automatically

Above code is **static** and **fixed** only for **3 array inputs** if there is a condition and the `$data` would be more than 3 then it will not work, so how can I use the code for **more or less** than **3 data variables**

For example, If the **input data** is like,

```
$data1 = array('1','2','3','4');
$data2 = array('1','2','3','4');
$data3 = array('1','2','3');
$data4 = array(5,6);
$data5 = array(7,8);
```

Then how to use the `loops` in that **case**.

Comment: What you want to generate automatically? an array? if is that so, just pass the counter values in a function parameter, like `function counter($end) {//loop}` and now use `$end` as for loop end counter

Comment: @Mr.Alien: can you provide an answer? I don't think that the solution is such easy!

Comment: @JasonOOO it's so easy, he needs 4, instead of 3, so the loop counter will end at 4, he needs a function, so he can simply pass an end counter value, now that's what I understand from his question

Comment: @Mr.Alien: no you are wrong, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959127/php-array-join-each-sub-array-together-probability

Comment: @JasonOOO Do you see the difference between numbers and letters?

Comment: I guess his question is hard to express, some one help him rephrase his words instead of flagging him and onhold his question?

Comment: @Irfan try this, `<?
function getArrayList( $arrList,$index=0){
$subList = $lists = '';
if ( $index < count( $arrList )-1 ){$subList = getArrayList( $arrList,  $index+1 );}
foreach( $arrList[$index] as $item ){$lists[$item]=$subList;}
return $lists;
}
$array = array(array(1,2,3),array(4,5),array(6,7),array(8,9));
$lists = getArrayList( $array );
function listData($lists,$d=array())
{foreach( $lists as $value => $r ){array_push( $d, $value );if ( is_array( $r ) ) {listData( $r, $d );}else{ echo implode( " ", $d ) ." <br/>";} array_pop( $d );  }}listData( $lists );
?>`

Answer (score 0):

What about having an array of those arrays instead and then you iterate through that array?

i.e.

```
$data = array(
    array('1','2','3','4'),
    array('1','2','3','4'),
    array('1','2','3')
);
```

I guess you know how to do the rest...