# Get all combos of given strings in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying something like

```
    $a=array("aaa","bbb","cccc","dddd");
$b=array();
foreach($a as $k=>$v){ 
$n=sizeof($a);
for($i=($k+1);$i<=$n;$i++) $b[]=$a[$k].$a[$i];
}
var_dump($b);
```

And I would like to have all kinds of glued strings in `$b` regardless of the array length of `$a`. I've tried different for loops which served partial solutions, maybe I'm not seeing the forest for the trees?

If I closer I'll post the upgraded code. Thanks for helping.

Comment: So you're either looking for all `permutations` or for a `powerset` of the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding cartesian product with PHP associative arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays)

Comment: One string in the array can not occur twice in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Cartesian Product Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays). It will generate every combination from the supplied arrays.