# Building an array of search parameters

Tags: php, arrays

I need some help wrapping my head around a problem. I have an array filled with other arrays. I need to:

1. Loop through the entire array and build a new array called `finalOptions`
2. Each iteration of the loop will take a new `SearchIndex` and apply the other paramenters

i.e

```
SearchIndex => SportingGoods
MinPercentageOff => 50
MinimumPrice => 1
ItemPage => 1
Sort => salesrank
BrowseNode => 2342470011
```

THEN:

**Final array should contain data like this**

```
SearchIndex => SportingGoods
MinPercentageOff => 60
MinimumPrice => 100
ItemPage => 2
Sort => salesrank
BrowseNode => 3403201
```

Basically, I'm creating a new array and sending it to another method that will execute a call to an API and return a result, then doing it again until my array options are complete.

This might not be the way to go and I'm looking for suggestions/pseudo code on an approach. Here is the basics of what I have so far:

**Starting with this code**

```
$allOptions = array(
    "SearchIndex"           => array("SportingGoods", "Tools"),
    "MinPercentageOff"      => array("50", "60", "70"),
    "MinimumPrice"          => array("1", "100", "1000"),
    "ItemPage"              => array("1", "2"),
    "Sort"                  => array("salesrank")
    "BrowseNode"            => array(
                                    "SportingGoods" => array("2342470011", "3403201"),
                                    "Tools"         => array("511364")
                            )
)

$finalOptions = array();

foreach($allOptions as $options){
    foreach($options["SearchIndex"] as $searchIndex){
        $finalOptions[] = "SearchIndex" => $searchIndex[]
    }


    $this->itemSearch($finalOptions);
}
```

**EDIT**

The arrays will contain more values. i.e `"ItemPage" => array("1", "2"),` will have 1 - 10. The others will have more values as well.

Comment: Can you make a bit clearer what you are starting with and what you want to end up with?

Comment: @MikeMiller I'm starting with the array `$allOptions` and I want to loop through it and build a new array called `$finalOptions`. `$finalOptions` should include an array similar to my second code block above. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: How do you differentiate number of values within your array. `Example : SearchIndex ` contains `2 array values ` while the right next contains `three`

Comment: @Uchiha that's part of where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to handle that. I'm open to other ideas

Comment: Might be you can differentiate those from query you were making

Comment: Do you want to generate all combinations possible for that ?

Comment: @Viral Yes, until `BrowseNode`. Then at that point, use the browse nodes that match the `SearchIndex` for the current iteration.

Comment: So you are only able to relate each sub arrays values by the index order? So all first values go together etc?

Comment: @MikeMiller The realtionship doesn't really matter other than `searchIndex` and `browseNode` those need to match

Comment: How do you know which MinPercentageOff relates to which BrowseNode? As another commenter said can you show your query as this might be easier solved further up the code chain

Comment: @MikeMiller Each `minPercentageOff` will be used on each `BrowseNode`. I'll see if I can add more code...

Comment: @MikeMiller I think it will be more confusing if I add more code. It's a large block of code that basically takes the new array created here and appends it to another array. That method makes a call to Amazon, returns a signed URL and then parses the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given array it will produce 54 possible combinations as you described.

Also you need to make sure you have array in `$allOptions['BrowseNode']` indexed as each value of `$allOptions['SearchIndex']`. Otherwise it will produce error.

Cartesian function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays/15973172#15973172).

```
$allOptions = [
    "SearchIndex"           => ["SportingGoods", "Tools"],
    "MinPercentageOff"      => ["50", "60", "70"],
    "MinimumPrice"          => ["1", "100", "1000"],
    "ItemPage"              => ["1", "2"],
    "Sort"                  => ["salesrank"],
    "BrowseNode"            => ["SportingGoods" => ["2342470011", "3403201"], "Tools" => ["511364"] ] ];


$finalOptions = $allOptions; // copy our initial $allOptions array

unset($finalOptions['BrowseNode']); // deal with BrowseNode key later with custom iterator

$cartesian_product = cartesian($finalOptions); // find cartesian except BrowseNode

foreach($cartesian_product as $cartesian) // each member of cartesian product will iterate here
{
    foreach($allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible)
    /*
        We have unset the BrowseNode, so need to refer original $allOptions array for BrowseNode,
        In every cartesian product, we will get $cartesian['SearchIndex'] and it will contain either
        'SportingGoods' or 'Tools' , so in our original array, look for 'BrowseNode' value, having key
        same as $cartesian['SearchIndex'].

        $allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] <---- is similar to below two lines

        $key = $cartesian['SearchIndex'];
        $allOptions['BrowseNode'][$key];

        Finally iterate through $allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] will iterate as many times,
        as many values there are
    */
    {
        $cartesian['BrowseNode'] = $possible; // assign the long waited key here to 'BrowseNode'
        var_dump($cartesian); // here you can do $this->itemSearch($cartesian);
    }
}

function cartesian($input) {

    $input = array_filter($input);
    /*  
        will renove any false values in input array,
        in our array's case, it will do nothing.
    */
    $result = [[]];

    foreach ($input as $key => $values) {
        $append = [];

        foreach($result as $product) {
            foreach($values as $item) {

                $product [$key] = $item;
                $append [] = $product;

            }
        }

        $result = $append;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out! So, the `cartesian` function will run, then the `foreach` loop gathers all possible combinations of `browseNodes` correct?

Comment: yes, Absolutely. Here `2 SportingGoods x 3 x 3 x 2 x 1` + `1 Tools x 3 x 3 x 2 x 1` = `54`

Comment: Two more questions: 1. What is `array_filter` used for here `$input = array_filter($input);` and, can you explain this: `foreach($allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible)`. I'm not clear on `$allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']]` is that comparing the values of the array keys?

Comment: I took the function from another [SO post here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15973172/3113793), but i can explain what it is doing, i will update my question with edits, i need some time for that as i am bad at explaining.