# Populating database field with multiple value

Tags: php, algorithm

I am working on populating the database tables. The table have fields which some of them are enum.

Consider a user which have a field `status` , whose values can be `active`, `inactive` etc. Assume we can modify the configuration values and running the script the data can be populated accordingly.

Let us represent the `user` table whose `status` field as

```
'status' => array(
   'active' => 3, 
   'inactive', 
   'deleted',
),
```

In this case assume we need to create 3 users with `status` , `active`. 1 user with status `inactive` and 1 with `deleted`.

The table may be having more enum fields. So the config can expand. Depending on the configuration and fields the values will be multiples.

Consider the below example.

Eg :

```
$config = array(
    'table1name' => array(
        'field1' => array(
            'active' => 3, 
            'inactive', 
            'deleted',
        ),
        'field2' => array(
            'admin', 
            'user', 
            'editor'
        ),
        ....,
        'more-fields' => array(
            'more-values', 
        )
    ),
    'table2name' => array(
        'field1' => array(
            'active', 
            'inactive', 
            'deleted',
        ),
    )
);
```

In this case there need to populate `table1` whose field `field1` with `active`, `inactive`, `deleted` and `roles` with `admin`, `user`, `editor` etc. ( The active, inactive etc are provided just for example. It can be just values. )

The idea is to generate more users depending on the count if any provided.

Eg :

```
'status' => array(
    'active' => 10, 
    'inactive' => 2, 
    'deleted' => 3,
),
'roles' => array(
    'admin' => 2, 
    'user', 
    'editor'
)
....,
'more-fields' => array(
    'more-values', 
)
```

So that there will be

10 * 4 => active users (10 * 2 active admin  / 10 active user, 10 active editor ) + 
2 * 4 => inactive users ( 2 inactive admin , 1 user, 1 editor ) + 
3 * 4 => deleted users in total.

I am struggling to build the algorithm for the same.

```
array(
    'status' => array(
        'active' => 10, 
        'inactive' => 2, 
        'deleted' => 3,
    ),
    'roles' => array(
        'admin' => 2, 
        'user', 
        'editor'
    ),
    ....,
    'more-fields' => array(
        'more-values', 
    )
)

// In this example you can see we have not covered the fields of the table when they are more than 1 on save.It looks we need to build the array with values first.

foreach ($config as $table => $fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $field => $values ) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $statusCount) {
            if (is_string($key)) {
                $model = new User();
                $model->$field = $key;
                $model->another = 'value';
                $model->save();
            } else {            
                for ($i = 0; $i< $statusCount; $i++) {
                    $model = new User();
                    $model->$field = $key;
                    $model->another = 'value';
                    $model->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE :

Changes made according to @the-fourth-bird answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33354032/487878

Problem is it only look for 2 fields, the fields can be 1 or n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a setup like this? (Not sure what the fields for the User can be, I used 'role' and 'admin' in this example.)

```
$fields = array(
    'status' => array(
        'active' => 10,
        'inactive' => 2,
        'deleted' => 3,
    ),
    'roles' => array(
        'admin',
        'user',
        'editor'
    )
);
$roles = $fields['roles'];
$statuses = $fields['status'];

foreach ($roles as $role) {
    foreach ($statuses as $status => $statusCount) {
        for ($i = 0; $i< $statusCount; $i++) {
            $model = new User();
            $model->role = $role;
            $model->status = $status;
        }
    }
}
```

**// Update with dynamic properties**

```
<?php
class table1name {
    public function save() {}
}
class table2name {
    public function save() {}
}
$config = array(
    'table1name' => array(
        'field1' => array(
            'active' => 3,
            'inactive',
            'deleted',
        ),
        'field2' => array(
            'admin',
            'user' => 2,
            'editor'
        ),
        'more-fields' => array(
            'more-values' => 2,
        ),
        'color' => array(
            'blue' => 2,
            'red'
        ),

    ),
    'table2name' => array(
        'field1' => array(
            'active',
            'inactive',
            'deleted',
        ),
    )
);

// Adjust data structure
// If the key is a string, turn the key into values for the given multiplier in the same array.
// Then unset the key.
foreach ($config as $table => $fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $field => $values ) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $statusCount) {
            if (is_string($key)) {
                for ($i = 0; $i< $statusCount; $i++) {
                    $config[$table][$field][] = $key;
                }
                unset($config[$table][$field][(string)$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$cartesians = [];

// If you want all the possible combinations for for example the 'table1name', you need a cartesian product. Used the function from this page:
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays
function cartesian($input) {
    $input = array_filter($input);
    $result = array(array());

    foreach ($input as $key => $values) {
        $append = array();
        foreach($result as $product) {
            foreach($values as $item) {
                $product[$key] = $item;
                $append[] = $product;
            }
        }
        $result = $append;
    }
    return $result;
}

// Create the cartesian products for all the keys in the $config array.
foreach ($config as $key => $tables) {
    $cartesians[$key] = cartesian($tables);
}

// Loop all the objects created by the cartesian function.
foreach ($cartesians as $objectName => $cartesian) {
    foreach($cartesian as $key => $value) {
        $model = new $objectName();
        $model->$key = $value;
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is nice, the problem is the fields are dynamic configuration based (it can be one to n). So we could not restrict it .

Comment: I've updated the code with another example to clarify the expected results. Is this example the dynamic configuration you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you, as I mentioned you cannot expect the roles / status are the fields. I was just giving a rough example. Consider the name of the fields change according to different table.

Comment: have modified the example to make it more clearer. Does this helps? Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my code example. The properties are now dynamic according to the table in the config array. Perhaps this idea can serve as a basis for your algorithm.