# cartesian product with PHP (id, name, variants)

Tags: php, associative-array, cartesian-product

Can you help me with generating caresian product.
It is similar to [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays). I want generate inputs so I need keep ID.

Example:

my input data:

```
[
  1 => [
    id => 1,
    name => "Color",
    options => [
       5 => [
         id => 5,
         name => "Red"
       ],
       6 => [
         id => 6,
         name => "Blue"
       ]
    ]
  ],
 2 => [
    id => 2,
    name => "Size",
    options => [
       7 => [
         id => 7,
         name => "S"
       ],
       8 => [
         id => 8,
         name => "M"
       ]
    ]
  ],

  // etc
]
```

result I expect:

```
[
 "5-7" => "Red / S",
 "5-8" => "Red / M",
 "6-7" => "Blue / S",
 "6-8" => "Blue / M"
]
```

I need generic function for any number of properties/options..

Comment: what have you tried so far? please post your code that you have tried first then we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I tried solution from other stackoverflow I wrote above, but it is not for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is actually working code for now but don't know how much is efficient.

```
// filter out properties without options
$withOptions = array_filter($properties, function($property) {
    return count($property['options']) > 0;
});

$result = [];

$skipFirst = true;

foreach ($withOptions as $property) {

    if ($skipFirst) {

        foreach (reset($withOptions)['options'] as $id => $option) {
            $result[$id] = $option['name'];
        }

        $skipFirst = false;
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($result as $code => $variant) {    
        foreach ($property['options'] as $id => $option) {
            $new = $code . "-" . $id;
            $result[$new] = $variant . " / " . $option['name'];
            unset($result[$code]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loop man, each entry of array 1 has to be linked with every entry of array2.

$finalArray = array();

```
foreach (array1 as $key1 as $value1){
  foreach (array2 as $key2 as$value2){
   echo  $value1 . " - " .$value2."<br/>";
   $finalArray[$key1.'-'.$key2] =   $value1 ." - ".$value2;
 }
}
```

the finalArray will be having what you need.

Comment: I need dynamics "function" for any number of "properties". There could be 2, 3, 4 .. any number of properties with options :)

Comment: that will work..just declare a new array and keep putting the key and values..let me update my answer

Comment: I see, but I can not edit function every time I add new properties, It must be generic for any number of properties. Maybe we don't understand each other :)

Comment: The post that you mentioned, did you try that solution? I got what you mean, you need dynamic number of arrays..

Comment: I tried that. But the output is different from my need. :) It combine all field so also id, name atc.. It similar problem but not same, so their solution cant fit to my..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I think he means that n number of sets/properties? Meaning its not just Color and Size just like in he's example. it may be 3 sets/properties