# Combine multiple array to another array

Tags: php, algorithm

i want combine 2 array like this

Example 1 :

```
Arr1 = ['A','B','C'],
Arr2 = ['D','E']
```

will be become

```
Arr3 = [
  ['A','D'],['A','E'],['B','D'],['B','E'],['',''] ....
]
```

Example 2 :

```
Arr1 = ['A','B','C'],
Arr2 = ['D','E']
Arr3 = ['G','H']
```

will be become

```
Arr4 = [
  ['A','D','G'],['A','E','G'],['','',''].... 
]
```

Any idea or suggest me algorithm can be like this thanks so much

Comment: Two foreach loops. Your second example (also named Ex1) is not detailed enough for us to know what is happening.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the cartesian product of two arrays. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313346/4548148) could help?

Comment: This my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays thanks so much my friend @tugayac

Comment: No worries, glad it was useful :)

Comment: Why the php tag?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version; merging array by index

```
$arr1 = range('a', 'b');
$arr2 = range('c', 'f');
$arr3 = range('g', 'k');
$arr4 = range('x', 'z');
$res  = array();

// $counter = 1;
// while ($counter <= 4) {
//   $array = "arr{$counter}";
//   funcIndexMerge($res, $$array);
//   $counter++;
// }

funcIndexMerge($res, $arr1);
funcIndexMerge($res, $arr2);
funcIndexMerge($res, $arr3);
funcIndexMerge($res, $arr4);
var_export($res);

function funcIndexMerge(&$res, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $ari => $val)  {
        if (!isset($res[$ari])) {
            $res[$ari] = array();
        }
        $res[$ari] = array_merge($res[$ari], array($val));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you suggest is very similar to this [Leetcode Challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/description/). The idea is to use [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

**Psuedo PsedoCode :**

```
result := string Array
CartesianProduct(rowIndex, ArrayList, stringSoFar):

if rowIndex equal ArrayList.size:
    Add stringSoFar to result
    return
for(eachItem in ArrayList[rowIndex])
    CartesianProduct(rowIndex +1 , ArrayList, stringSoFar + eachItem)
    return
```

This is a workhorse which does all the computation and can be called like `CartesianProduct(0, list of Array to be multiplied, "")`

Suppose your `ArrayList = [['A'], ['C', 'D']]`. And `CP` be `CartesianProduct`

```
                 CP(0, AL, "")
            (Take 'A')/
                     /
               CP(1, AL, "A") (stringSoFar becomes 'A')
         (Take C) /       \(Take 'D'.Second Iteration with second array['C', 'D']) 
                 /         \
         CP(2, AL, "AC")  CP(2, AL, "AD")
              /              \
  rowIndex equal size.   rowIndex equals listSize i.e No more list to look
  Add "AC" and return    Add stringsoFar ("AD") to result and rerturn
```

My solution to the Leetcode problem(but in C++). Hopefully it'll give you some idea to write in PHP

```
class Solution {
public:
    map<char, vector<string>> values {
    {'2', vector<string>{"a", "b", "c"}},
    {'3', vector<string>{"d", "e", "f"}},
    {'4', vector<string>{"g", "h", "i"}},
    {'5', vector<string>{"j", "k", "l"}},
    {'6', vector<string>{"m", "n", "o"}},
    {'7', vector<string>{"p", "q", "r", "s"}},
    {'8', vector<string>{"t", "u", "v"}},
    {'9', vector<string>{"w", "x", "y", "z"}}
    };
vector<string> answer;
void doComb(int index, string digits, string sofar)
{
    if(index == digits.size())
    {
        if(sofar != "")
        {
            answer.push_back(sofar);    
        }
        return;
    }
    for(auto lett : values[digits[index]])
    {
        doComb(index + 1, digits, sofar + lett);
    }
    return;
}
vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
    doComb(0, digits, "");
    return answer;
    }
};
```