# PHP or JavaScript iterate infinite number of arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, foreach

I am facing a challange, I have three arrays, each array contains only numbers. 
I have a function `get_sum` the function receives 2 parameters, an array of arrays and a number. The number is a sum I want to receive from summing one or more number from each array, for example: 
If I have 2 arrays `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]` and the second parameter is `4`
the function will return the number of combinations that will sum an amount of 4. in this case:

```
1+3 = 4
2+2 = 4
3+1 = 4
```

So the function will retun the int `3`

I wrote the function below, and it works great but I am looking for a way to make it more efficient. At the moment it will work if I have less than 6 arrays, I want it to work if I have a hundred arrays.
Is there any array function that can help me here?

This is the code:

```
<?php
function get_sum ($dice, $sum) {
    $sumcount = array();
    $num_of_dice = count($dice);    
    foreach($dice[0] as $die1){
        foreach($dice[1] as $die2){
            if($num_of_dice == 5){
                foreach($dice[2] as $die3){
                    foreach($dice[3] as $die4){
                        foreach($dice[4] as $die5){
                            if($die1 + $die2 + $die3+ $die4 + $die5 == $sum){
                                $good_res = array();
                                array_push( $good_res, $die1, $die2, $die3, $die4, $die5);
                                array_push($sumcount, $good_res);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if($num_of_dice == 4){
                foreach($dice[2] as $die3){
                    foreach($dice[3] as $die4){
                        if($die1 + $die2 + $die3+ $die4 == $sum){
                            $good_res = array();
                            array_push( $good_res, $die1, $die2, $die3, $die4);
                            array_push($sumcount, $good_res);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }elseif ($num_of_dice == 3){
                foreach($dice[2] as $die3){
                    if($die1 + $die2 + $die3 == $sum){
                        $good_res = array();
                        array_push( $good_res, $die1, $die2, $die3);
                        array_push($sumcount, $good_res);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if($die1 + $die2 == $sum){
                    $good_res = array();
                    array_push( $good_res, $die1, $die2);
                    array_push($sumcount, $good_res);
                }
            }

        }
    };



    echo count($sumcount);
}



get_sum([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], 9)
?>
```

If there is a function in JavaScript it will be good as well.

Thanks

Comment: Seeing as you have a working function it might be worth asking this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 5):

#### Idea

The idea is that to create a *Cartesian Product* of all elements for all arrays together and then count the rows that give the expected sum.

#### JavaScript

In *JavaScript ES6* this idea can be implemented like this:

```
const simpleCartesian = (arr1, arr2) => [].concat( ...arr1.map( el1 => arr2.map( el2 => [].concat( el1, el2 ) ) ) );
const fullCartesian = (arr1, arr2, ...arrN) => (arr2 ? fullCartesian(simpleCartesian(arr1, arr2), ...arrN) : arr1);
const reduceSum = (a, b) => a + b;
const getSum = (arr, sum) =>  fullCartesian(...arr).reduce((prev, currArr) => prev += currArr.reduce(reduceSum) == sum ? 1 : 0, 0);
```

The functions `simpleCartesian`, `fullCartesian` and `reduceSum` are auxiliary for the `getSum` function.

In use:

```
getSum( [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], 9)
// Returned value: 25
```

#### PHP

In *PHP* this idea can be implemented for example like this:

```
function cartesian_product($arrays) {
    $cartesian_product = [[]];
    foreach ($arrays as $key => $arr) {
        $appendArr = [];
        foreach ($cartesian_product as $product) {
            foreach ($arr as $item) {
                $product[$key] = $item;
                $appendArr[] = $product;
            }
        }
        $cartesian_product = $appendArr;
    }
    return $cartesian_product;
}
function get_sum($arrays, $sum) {
    $counter = 0;
    $cartesian_product = cartesian_product($arrays);
    foreach ($cartesian_product as $row) {
        if ($sum == array_sum($row)) {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    return $counter;
}
```

The function `cartesian_product` is auxiliary for the `get_sum` function.

In use:

```
get_sum( [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]], 7);
// Returned value: 15
```

#### Optimization

We need to know that creating a full array with a **Cartesian Product consuming a lot of memory** when we use many arrays or some very big arrays.

- If we assume that the elements of tables are **non-negative**, we can optimize that algorithm by **remove all elements equal to or larger than *sum parameter* from the input tables**, before creating a Cartesian Product.
- If we assume that the elements of tables are **positive**, we can optimize that algorithm by **remove all elements equal to or larger than *sum parameter minus count of input arrays* from the input tables**, before creating a Cartesian Product.

#### Thanks

Special thanks for [@rsp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053803) and [@SergiySokolenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15973172) for their answers about the implementation of a *Cartesian Product* in *JavaScript* and *PHP*.

Comment: This is a good solution but...... for many-many arrays, I think it will eat up the memory pretty fast!

Comment: @dkellner thank you for your observation. I added a note about optimization.

Comment: Hi @DavSev!

Does this answer satisfy you or do you expect something else?