# PHP Shuffle Unique Values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get this output from array

```
$properties = array(
    1 => array('one', 'two'),
    2 => array('red', 'blue'),
    3 => array('active', 'not-active'),
);
```

- one_red_active
- one_red_not-active
- one_blue_active
- one_blue_not-active
- two_red_active
- two_red_not-active
- two_blue_active
- two_blue_not-active

Thx!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far ? Please update your question with your code attempt.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779) will help.

Comment: your question is a bit vague... what are you looking for? is it the cleanest way of combining all the possible array values with an underscore? the first thing that comes into my mind is nested for each... or with an iterator variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. Simple, but based on your question: it should suffice.

```
<?php

  $properties = array(
    1 => array('one', 'two'),
    2 => array('red', 'blue'),
    3 => array('active', 'not-active'),
  );

  /*echo "<pre>";
  print_R($properties);
  echo "</pre>";*/
  //Not needed but stil useful for troubleshooting.

  foreach ($properties[1] as $value_array_one) {
    foreach ($properties[2] as $value_array_two) {
      foreach ($properties[3] as $value_array_three) {
        echo $value_array_one . "_" . $value_array_two . "_" . $value_array_three . "<br/>";
      }
    }
  }

?>
```