# How to generate multiple combinations from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am importing products from one platform to another using CSV. I have successfully created arrays of products from the CSV file but have difficulty creating variations from these product arrays.

A product array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Test Product
    [Price] => 50
    [Options] => Array
        (
            ['Color'] => Array
                (
                    ['Red'] => 10
                    ['Green'] => 20
                )

            ['Size'] => Array
                (
                    ['Small'] => 30
                    ['Medium'] => 40
                )

        )

)
```

The desired output for the variations array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Test Product - Red, Small
            [Regular price] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Test Product - Red, Medium
            [Regular price] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Test Product - Green, Small
            [Regular price] => 100
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Test Product - Green, Medium
            [Regular price] => 110
        )

)
```

My PHP code is as follows

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    $product = array(
        "Name" => "Test Product",
        "Price" => 50,
        "Options" => array(
            "'Color'" => array(
                "'Red'" => 10,
                "'Green'" => 20,
            ),
            "'Size'" => array(
                "'Small'" => 30,
                "'Medium'" => 40,
            )
        ),
    );
    print_r($product);
    
    $variations = array();
    foreach ($product["Options"] as $option) {
        foreach ($option as $name => $price) {
            $name = str_replace("'", "", $name);
            array_push($variations, array(
                "Name" => "Test Product - ${name}",
                "Price" => (int)$product["Regular price"] + $price,
            ));
        }
    }
    print_r($variations);
```

I am stuck on combining the `Options`. The goal is to merge the options. I tried various possibilities using the `for` loop and the nested `for` loop but had no luck. Can someone please guide me in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: This is the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/15973172/3807365 it is called cartesian product of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat of a cartesian product of N arrays. See comments for references.

Explanation: The real trick here is to create the arrays multiplication. For that I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15973172/3807365). Please `print_r` the resulting array after `cartesian` and you'll see how it multiplied the arrays.

Next step is just printing them nicely. Another hurdle is to get the values of the price back for each item ("red", "green" etc) and for that I just use the original array looking for the correct prices.

I admit, there are a lot of `array_keys`, `array_values` and `array_map` there. Maybe could have made this entire solution inside one function. But I went with reusing the `cartesian` without changing it.

```php
function cartesian($input)
{
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($input as $key => $values) {
        $append = array();
        foreach ($result as $product) {
            foreach ($values as $item) {
                $product[$key] = $item;
                $append[] = $product;
            }
        }
        $result = $append;
    }
    return $result;
}

$arr = array(
    "Name" => "Test Product",
    "Price" => 50,
    "Options" => array(
        'Color' => array(
            'Red' => 10,
            'Green' => 20,
        ),
        'Size' => array(
            'Small' => 30,
            'Medium' => 40,
        ),
    ),
);

$options = array_map('array_keys', $arr["Options"]);

$combinations = cartesian($options);

$result = array_map(function ($combo) use ($arr) {
    // get prices
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($combo as $key => $value) {
        $total += $arr['Options'][$key][$value];
    }
    return [
        'name' => $arr['Name'] . " - " . implode(", ", array_values($combo)),
        'Regular price' => $arr['Price'] + $total,
    ];

}, $combinations);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test Product - Red, Small
            [Regular price] => 90
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test Product - Red, Medium
            [Regular price] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test Product - Green, Small
            [Regular price] => 100
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test Product - Green, Medium
            [Regular price] => 110
        )

)
```

Comment: Yes, it prints the exact output! Can you please add some comments explaining the code?