# Outputting every possible product option

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I used to be able to get my head around things like this in my sleep, but since leaving the dev world 7+ years ago, I've lost the dev brain...

My scenario is that I'm trying to output every possible product option that a customer can select, and the resulting SKU - made up of each option SKU appended to the product SKU.

The data isn't stored very well, as it's a pretty archaic site.

Below is an example of how the data is stored in MySQL, and what I am trying to achieve in PHP.  I've limited it to one product with many options.

| products.id | products.sku |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |

| options.id | options.product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

| option_values.id | option_values.option_id | option_values.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | b |
| 2 | 1 | c |
| 3 | 1 | d |
| 4 | 2 | e |
| 5 | 2 | f |
| 6 | 3 | g |
| 7 | 3 | h |
| 8 | 4 | i |
| 9 | 4 | j |
| 10 | 4 | k |

Iterating over every possible combination of option(s), and output the resulting SKUs;

| Possible SKUs |
| --- |
| abegi |
| acegi |
| adegi |
| abfgi |
| acfgi |
| adfgi |
| abehi |
| acehi |
| adehi |
| abegj |
| acegj |
| adegj |
| abegk |
| acegk |
| adegk |
| [etc] |

It seems very simple when I write it out like this, which makes me wonder if I'm missing something...

I'm currently iterating over every product, and for each product every option, then for each option every value, but obviously this doesn't cater for every possible scenario.

DB Fiddle - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHWiKsKi9WUvvDwAa6pqw6/0

Thank you!

Comment: please include your query.  If you would build a db fiddle that would make it a lot easier to answer (some have text to ddl functions you can paste in the source markdown of your tables)

Comment: It would be even better if you created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT) with this test data so we can all have a play and test our answers before submitting them

Comment: Thanks for your input @erik258 I've created a DB Fiddle - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHWiKsKi9WUvvDwAa6pqw6/0

Comment: Thanks for your input @RiggsFolly I've created a DB Fiddle - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHWiKsKi9WUvvDwAa6pqw6/0

Comment: @nnichols currently approx 1500 products, ranging from 0 options to 6+ options, which each option having any where between 2 and 20 values. I would like the processing to be done in PHP, rather than MySQL.

Comment: @nnichols do you have an example please? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHWiKsKi9WUvvDwAa6pqw6/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to create the cartesian product of all the options is inspired by the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6311779).

```php
<?php

function all_skus(array $product) {
    $skus = [];
    $result = [[]];

    foreach ($product['options'] as $key => $option) {
        $append = [];
        foreach ($result as $options) {
            foreach ($option as $value) {
                $append[] = $options + [$key => $value];
            }
        }
        $result = $append;
    }

    foreach ($result as $option_set) {
        $skus[] = $product['sku'] . implode($option_set);
    }

    return $skus;
}


$pdo = new PDO(/* your stuff here */);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$res = $pdo->query('
            SELECT `o`.`product_id`, `p`.`sku`, `ov`.`option_id`, `ov`.`value`
            FROM `products` `p`
            JOIN `options` `o` ON `p`.`id` = `o`.`product_id`
            JOIN `option_values` `ov` ON `o`.`id` = `ov`.`option_id`'
        );

$nested = [];
foreach ($res as $row) {
    $nested[$row->product_id]['options'][$row->option_id][] = $row->value;
    $nested[$row->product_id]['sku'] = $row->sku;
}

$skus = [];
foreach ($nested as $i => $product) {
    $skus = array_merge($skus, all_skus($product));
    unset($nested[$i]);
}

var_dump($skus);
```

If you are only interested in the sku strings you can reduce the function to:

```php
function all_skus(array $product) {
    $result = [$product['sku']];

    foreach ($product['options'] as $option) {
        $append = [];
        foreach ($result as $options) {
            foreach ($option as $value) {
                $append[] = $options . $value;
            }
        }
        $result = $append;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I am sure someone can provide a more efficient answer but this does produce the output requested, based on your example data.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much!  I should be able to extend it further now - some options are radio buttons, so only one value can be chosen, whilst others are checkboxes, so multiple values can be chosen, and so even more SKUs.

Comment: I made a small change and dropped the fetchAll to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: Thank you - I'm using it inside Laravel, so converting the code over