# Something with arrays that I dont really know what to call

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
1 => array
    0 => string '1'
    1 => string '2'
2 => array
    0 => string '7'
    1 => string '8'
```

And I want to create some objects, in this case 4, size of the first times size of the second.

So I would get:

```
Object(1,7)
Object(1,8)
Object(1,7)
Object(2,8)
```

The problem is, I dont know the size of the first array so it could be like this

```
1 => array
    0 => string '1'
    1 => string '2'
2 => array
    0 => string '7'
    1 => string '8'
3 => array
    0 => string '9'
    1 => string '10'
```

So I would get:

```
Object(1,7,9)
Object(1,7,10)
Object(1,8,9)
Object(1,8,10)
Object(2,7,9)
Object(2,7,10)
Object(2,8,9)
Object(2,8,10)
```

And It could be even bigger.

Sorry for the bad explanation, I cant think of a better way to explain it.

So the question is, how would I go and implement this?
preferably in PHP but Java, C, C++ solutions are accepted since I can relatively easily convert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the "cartesian product" of your arrays. The first step would be to do something like this: [Concatenate values of n arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246493/concatenate-values-of-n-arrays-in-php)

You would then have to convert the arrays to objects, which should not be a challenge.