# How to union 2 arrays depending the key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem to join two array in only one. I try to use array_marge. But this property doesn't work for me.

I have these arrays.

```
$Record1=Array(
    [647242M40642NGG916] => 647242|M40642NGG916|10,
    [647242M40725NG6621] => 647242|M40725NG6621|11,
    [647242M40732NG0287] => 647242|M40732NG0287|11,
    [647242M90830FYIF18] => 647242|M90830FYIF18|10,
    [647242M91221EXDU57] => 647242|M91221EXDU57|11,
    [647242M91304EX8878] => 647242|M91304EX8878|10)

$Record2=Array(
    [647242M40642NGG916] => |96
    [647242M40725NG6621] => |95
    [647242M40732NG0287] => |99
    [647242M90830FYIF18] => |93
    [647242M91221EXDU57] => |99
    [647242M91304EX8878] => |92)
```

if I use the property array_merge the array2 replace the values of the first array.

and I want join the values depending of the key  and plus the value that I have in the first Array.

I want find this result.

```
$Record3=Array(
    [647242M40642NGG916] => 647242|M40642NGG916|10|96,
    [647242M40725NG6621] => 647242|M40725NG6621|11|95,
    [647242M40732NG0287] => 647242|M40732NG0287|11|99,
    [647242M90830FYIF18] => 647242|M90830FYIF18|10|93,
    [647242M91221EXDU57] => 647242|M91221EXDU57|11|99,
    [647242M91304EX8878] => 647242|M91304EX8878|10|92)
```

Could you please  help me with this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate values of n arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246493/concatenate-values-of-n-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems your two arrays has the same keys and you want to merge the value of each key. Then you need to make your hands dirty by writing own code instead of any php builtin function.

You can do this as the following way:

```
foreach($Record1 as $key => $value){
    $Record1[$key] .= isset($Record2[$key]) ? $Record2[$key] : '';
}
var_dump($Record1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to apply logic to every element of your array.

```
array_walk($Record1, function () use (&$Record1, $Record2) {
    $key = key($Record1);
    // Check if the key exists in both arrays
    if (array_key_exists($key, $Record2)) {
        $Record1[$key] = $Record1[$key] . '' . $Record2[$key];
    }
    next($Record1);
});

var_dump($Record1);
```

**Result:**

```
array (size=6)
  '647242M40642NGG916' => string '647242|M40642NGG916|10|96' (length=25)
  '647242M40725NG6621' => string '647242|M40725NG6621|11|95' (length=25)
  '647242M40732NG0287' => string '647242|M40732NG0287|11|99' (length=25)
  '647242M90830FYIF18' => string '647242|M90830FYIF18|10|93' (length=25)
  '647242M91221EXDU57' => string '647242|M91221EXDU57|11|99' (length=25)
  '647242M91304EX8878' => string '647242|M91304EX8878|10|92' (length=25)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, merge arrays on base of keys and then concatenate rows corresponding to the same key

```
$res = array_merge_recursive($Record1, $Record2);
$res = array_map('join', $res);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/938296)